# Tips for moderating a panel discussion: Optimum number of panelists?

Tags: conference

I will be moderating a panel discussion (60 min event) later this Semester. Was wondering if there are any tips that people may have?

I have read some of the relevant questions on Academia SE. e.g. [This](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/132314/tips-for-managing-a-panel-at-a-conference) and [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32008/how-should-i-facilitate-a-panel-discussion)  but would love more insights.

e.g. What's an optimum number of speakers? Typically in the past I've moderated panels with two or three panelists but this time it seems we might have four.

Is four too many? i.e. I worry each speaker gets too little time or the discussion becomes too disjoint.

Would love comments about what others feel. Even if you have not moderated a panel I am sure most of us have listened to one.

What are things that you love and hate?

e.g. Personally I feel panels almost always give too little time for audience questions and that's usually where the most interesting part lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. 4-6 sounds right, but you have to have a good moderator.
2. Don't let them ramble for 10 minutes, or you will burn all time on the intro.
3. Prepare good questions, slightly controversial or provocative is ok, but don't force them to become defensive, that's no fun, this is not "The Weakest Link" (a show where more and more  "weak" candidates are dismissed, usually condescendingly, from the selection)
4. You may want to try out the topic with your organizers and see how it works. Practice the moderation and the transitions and how you will handle the audience. Ramblers are not exclusively on the panel.

Comment: Excellent comments! Thanks. That's the sort of feedback I wanted!